# Cant find reporting services in sql server 2017 setup

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

When I come to feature selection part of setup I get message:

> Looking for reporting services? Download them here...

I already have reporting services downloaded and installed.

Deinstalled and restarted pc few times, nothing changes,
not sure what else can I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017):

> SQL Server Reporting Services installation involves server components
>   for storing report items, rendering reports, and processing of
>   subscription and other report services. To download SQL Server 2017
>   Reporting Services, go to the [Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252).

It was moved out of the SQL Installer, but is still licensed as part of SQL Server.  A single team owns both SQL Server Reporting Services, and [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/) so they were both made to ship as downloads.

Comment: basically i already downloaded ssrs from that site my problem is even thought i have ssrs installed and ssrs in services is active, reporting services wont show in feature sellection when creating new server

Answer (score 1):

> I already have reporting services downloaded and installed.
>   Deinstalled and restarted pc few times, nothing changes, not sure what
>   else can I do?

You have nothing to do with that warning of installer, just go ahead and install your data engine. As David Browne mentioned, SSRS 2017 is a separate package now and to be installed separately, but seems you already made this.

When SSRS is installed you have to open Reporting Services Configuration Manager to run initial instance configuration